# Spacing with additional units in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I want to write geographical positions with siunitx. I think that in this notation there should be no space between number and degree symbol and also none between degree symbol and N/S or E/W notation, just like in degree celsius. So I would normally type `53,5$^\circ$N` in regular LaTeX.

I try to achieve that by writing the following with siunitx:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\north}{N}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\SI{53,5}{\degree}\\
\SI{53,5}{\degree\north}\\
53,5$^\circ$N

\end{document}
```

But what I get is:

[image: degrees]

And I don't get, why siunitx is adding the space between number and degree symbol, as well as between degree symbol and N.

Comment: These are not units.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not units, *stricto sensu*, but `siunitx` is flexible enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\north}{\degree N}
\DeclareSIUnit{\south}{\degree S}
\DeclareSIUnit{\east}{\degree E}
\DeclareSIUnit{\west}{\degree W}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xtude}{O{}mm}{%
  \SI[number-unit-product={},#1]{#2}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}

The latitude is \xtude{53,5}{\north}

The longitude is \xtude{45.3}{\east}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\north}{\!\degree N}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\SI{53,5}{\degree}\\
\SI{53,5}{\north}\\
53,5$^\circ$N

\end{document}
```